# KeyError when using Twitter REST API

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy, keyerror

I am using Tweepy and the Twitter REST API but am getting a KeyError when I do so. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
print(api.get_status(id)._json['text'])
print("Retweet count:", api.get_status(id)._json['retweet_count'])
print("Favorite count:", api.get_status(id)._json['favorite_count'])
print(api.get_status(id)._json['reply_count'])
```

Output:

```
[text]

Retweet count: 255
Favorite count: 394
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./demo_scraper.py", line 37, in <module>
  print(api.get_status(930429461165760512)._json['reply_count'])
  KeyError: 'reply_count'
```

But I see 'reply_count' in the Twitter docs here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

Comment: Does `'reply_count'` exist in `print(api.get_status(id)._json)`?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I check for that?

Comment: I thought so because of the Twitter docs (linked above).

Comment: Do add this line: `print(api.get_status(id)._json)` and see if `'reply_count'` exits in printed lines.

Comment: Ah, no, it does not upon further inspection. Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be accessing `_json` directly

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `reply_count` does not get returned from the get_status() tweepy function, despite being an attribute of a tweet object.